# Turtlebot Indigo install from source failing to get rocon source

Tags: ros, turtlebot, source, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I attempt to install the Indigo version of the Turtlebot package from source using the instructions here:

http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/indigo/Installation

When I run this step:

```
wstool init -j5 src https://raw.github.com/robotics-in-concert/rocon/indigo/rocon.rosinstall
```

It ends with this error:

```
WARNING [vcstools] Command failed: 'git checkout hydro-devel'
 run at: '/home/myuser/rocon/src/rosbridge_suite'
 errcode: 1:
error: pathspec 'hydro-devel' did not match any file(s) known to git.
[/vcstools]
Exception caught during install: Error processing 'rocon_concert' : [rocon_concert] Checkout of https://github.com/robotics-in-concert/rocon_concert.git version indigo into /home/myuser/rocon/src/rocon_concert failed.
Error processing 'rosbridge_suite' : [rosbridge_suite] Checkout of https://github.com/RobotWebTools/rosbridge_suite.git version hydro-devel into /home/myuser/rocon/src/rosbridge_suite failed.

ERROR in config: Error processing 'rocon_concert' : [rocon_concert] Checkout of https://github.com/robotics-in-concert/rocon_concert.git version indigo into /home/myuser/rocon/src/rocon_concert failed.
Error processing 'rosbridge_suite' : [rosbridge_suite] Checkout of https://github.com/RobotWebTools/rosbridge_suite.git version hydro-devel into /home/myuser/rocon/src/rosbridge_suite failed.
```

Is there something wrong with the repository, the instructions, or did I miss something somewhere?

**This appears to fix the problem, based on the accepted answer:**

```
mkdir ~/rocon
cd ~/rocon
wget https://raw.github.com/robotics-in-concert/rocon/indigo/rocon.rosinstall
vi rocon.rosinstall
```

REMOVE this line:

```
{'git': {'local-name': 'rosbridge_suite', 'version': 'hydro-devel', 'uri': 'https://github.com/RobotWebTools/rosbridge_suite.git'}},
```

Then install the rosbridge-suite from deb:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-rosbridge-suite
```

And  use your edited .rosinstall file to pull everything else from github:

```
wstool init -j5 src rocon.rosinstall
```

If this fails, with an error like:

```
Exception caught during install: Error processing 'rocon' : [rocon] Checkout of https://github.com/robotics-in-concert/rocon.git version indigo into /home/chrisl8/rocon/src/rocon failed.

ERROR in config: Error processing 'rocon' : [rocon] Checkout of https://github.com/robotics-in-concert/rocon.git version indigo into /home/chrisl8/rocon/src/rocon failed.
```

Just try again like this:

```
rm -rf src
wstool init -j5 src rocon.rosinstall
```

It appears that github sometimes has timeouts or something.

Then continue with the instructions . . .

```
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
rosdep install --from-paths src -i -y
catkin_make
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188073/turtlebot-indigo-install-from-source-failing-to-get-rocon-source/) by [ChrisL8](https://answers.ros.org/users/19020/chrisl8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 241 on 2014-07-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rosbridge moved their branches recently, just remove that one from the rosinstall and install the deb instead (at the time of writing, there was no rosbridge deb yet). Jihoon will update the rosinstaller to be correct shortly.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2014-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This came up recently on the ros-users mailing list. I think the indigo rosinstall file needs a little bit of tweaking.

See: http://lists.ros.org/pipermail/ros-users/2014-July/068820.html and the follow-up: http://lists.ros.org/pipermail/ros-users/2014-July/068822.html

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

this occurs again when i re-setup all code on the laptop according to the wiki..

> Exception caught during install: Error
> processing 'yocs_msgs' : [yocs_msgs]
> Checkout of
> https://github.com/yujinrobot/yocs_msgs.git
> version indigo into
> /home/turtlebot/turtlebot/kobuki/src/yocs_msgs
> failed.
>
> ERROR in config: Error processing
> 'yocs_msgs' : [yocs_msgs] Checkout of
> https://github.com/yujinrobot/yocs_msgs.git
> version indigo into
> /home/turtlebot/turtlebot/kobuki/src/yocs_msgs
> failed.

and also the same with **rocon_concert** package.

even pull down from git warehouse,

> https://github.com/yujinrobot/yocs_msgs

will also cause build error:

> [  4%] Built target ftdi_write_eeprom
> [  4%] Building CXX object
> kobuki_core/kobuki_dock_drive/CMakeFiles/kobuki_dock_drive.dir/src/dock_drive.cpp.o
> Scanning dependencies of target kobuki
> In file included from
> /home/turtlebot/turtlebot/kobuki/src/kobuki_core/kobuki_dock_drive/src/dock_drive.cpp:38:0:
> /home/turtlebot/turtlebot/kobuki/src/kobuki_core/kobuki_dock_drive/include/kobuki_dock_drive/dock_drive.hpp:51:42:
> fatal error:
> ecl/geometry/legacy_pose2d.hpp: no
> that file  #include
> <ecl/geometry/legacy_pose2d.hpp>
> ^

compilation terminated.

---

Originally posted by [asimay_y](https://answers.ros.org/users/20955/asimay_y/) with karma: 255 on 2016-09-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tixiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/20747/tixiao/) on 2016-10-08**:
I am also having this problem right now. It seems that they don't want any people to use Turtlebot now.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2016-10-08**:
Some of the repositories were restructured and don't have the indigo branch anymore. I've ticketed it here: https://github.com/yujinrobot/yujin_tools/issues/104 for those repos you likely need to adjust the branch name to something like `release/0.6-indigo`

**Comment by [YoungYusheng](https://answers.ros.org/users/28578/youngyusheng/) on 2016-11-19**:
I also have the same problem, When I did like you say "This appears to fix the problem, based on the accepted answer:",,I got this "404：Not Found " . Did anyone deal with the problem?